# Python 3.7.4 .....Unable to install hdbscan

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to install hdbscan in Jupyter Notebook,but nothing happens ( pip install hdbscan ), pip is up to date, python version: 3.7.4. Then I tried installing hdbscan on Pycharm, it shows following error: [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxVjB.jpg).

**Pycharm**

Error Occurred:
*error: command 'E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2*

Command Output:

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/2f/2423d844072f007a74214c1adc46260e45f034bb1679ccadfbb8a601f647/hdbscan-0.8.26.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting joblib (from hdbscan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/dd/0e015051b4a27ec5a58b02ab774059f3289a94b0906f880a3f9507e74f38/joblib-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.0 in c:\users\rocky\pycharmprojects\beginning\venv\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.17.2)
Collecting scipy>=0.9 (from hdbscan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/af/21729642100b4fa7c48c0aafd5751e1db17c06be82958dd220fe0f52fbfd/scipy-1.5.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.17 (from hdbscan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/89/73453581aeb9e0b8aac7cf6e9ba014af62b6128e5388e25eb0c7447fedbe/scikit_learn-0.23.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\rocky\pycharmprojects\beginning\venv\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.12.0)
Collecting cython>=0.27 (from hdbscan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/fe/4712646364a86a9faa1e80f666a0e78cb13c17357186fc6a04ed5c3d6d31/Cython-0.29.21-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 (from scikit-learn>=0.17->hdbscan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/12/ec3f2e203afa394a149911729357aa48affc59c20e2c1c8297a60f33f133/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: hdbscan
  Building wheel for hdbscan (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for hdbscan (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\RocKY\PycharmProjects\Beginning\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\RocKY\PycharmProjects\Beginning\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py build_wheel C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpe0ptnhgb:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\hdbscan_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\plots.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\prediction.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\robust_single_linkage_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\validity.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_hdbscan.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_rsl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
  
  running build_ext
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fe7bpus1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fe7bpus1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fe7bpus1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_reachability.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fe7bpus1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_prediction_utils.pyx to hdbscan\_prediction_utils.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fe7bpus1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hdbscan\hdbscan\_prediction_utils.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/dist_metrics.pyx to hdbscan\dist_metrics.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fe7bpus1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hdbscan\hdbscan\dist_metrics.pxd
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'hdbscan._hdbscan_tree' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\hdbscan
  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\RocKY\PycharmProjects\Beginning\venv\include -IC:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fe7bpus1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IE:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IE:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tchdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.obj
  _hdbscan_tree.c
  c:\users\rocky\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(203): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for hdbscan
Failed to build hdbscan

  Failed building wheel for hdbscan
Could not build wheels for hdbscan which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

**Visual Studio 2019**

```
----- Installing 'hdbscan' -----
Collecting hdbscan
  Using cached hdbscan-0.8.26.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting joblib
  Using cached joblib-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (300 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in c:\users\rocky\source\repos\pythonapplication1\pythonapplication1\env\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.15.0)
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.17
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.23.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (5.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=0.9 in c:\users\rocky\source\repos\pythonapplication1\pythonapplication1\env\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.5.2)
Collecting cython>=0.27
  Using cached Cython-0.29.21-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (1.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.16.0 in c:\users\rocky\source\repos\pythonapplication1\pythonapplication1\env\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.19.1)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: hdbscan
  Building wheel for hdbscan (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for hdbscan (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\RocKY\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\env\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\RocKY\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazs0u_he'
       cwd: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j87umtng\hdbscan
  Complete output (43 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\hdbscan_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\plots.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\prediction.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\robust_single_linkage_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\validity.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_hdbscan.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_rsl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\hdbscan\tests
  running build_ext
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c
Failed to build hdbscan
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1eaya_1w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j87umtng\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1eaya_1w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j87umtng\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1eaya_1w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j87umtng\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_reachability.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1eaya_1w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j87umtng\hdbscan\hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/_prediction_utils.pyx to hdbscan\_prediction_utils.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1eaya_1w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j87umtng\hdbscan\hdbscan\_prediction_utils.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  cythoning hdbscan/dist_metrics.pyx to hdbscan\dist_metrics.c
  C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1eaya_1w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j87umtng\hdbscan\hdbscan\dist_metrics.pxd
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'hdbscan._hdbscan_tree' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\hdbscan
  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\RocKY\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\env\include -IC:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\RocKY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1eaya_1w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IE:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IE:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tchdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.obj
  _hdbscan_tree.c
  c:\users\rocky\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(203): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
----- Failed to install 'hdbscan' -----
```

Comment: did you try installing it from terminal like the error suggests?

Comment: Yes I tried...Now tried in Visual Studio 2019...I've attached the error output

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering python version on your machine, it might help.